# AutoIt: Send("{DOWN}") not working

Tags: autoit

I am running an "autoit3.chm" file. When it runs, I would like to send a down key arrow but it doesn't work:

```
$file = FileGetShortName("C:\Users\PHSD100-SIC\Desktop\AutoIt3.chm")
Run(@ComSpec & " /c start " & $file)
WinWaitActive("AutoIT Help")
Send("{DOWN}")
```

Comment: *not working* you mean no response ?

Comment: the `send("{DOWN}")` did not work

Comment: Well, it would have worked, if the script would have reached this line of code... But look at my answer below... you misspelled **AutoIt**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're just waiting for the wrong Window Title... Try `WinWaitActive("AutoIt Help")` and it will work... Your "**T**" must be a "**t**"...
To find this out, you just need to check your script output and after your CHM-File has been opened you'll see that your script is still running. But you would have expected it to execute the `Send(...)` and then terminate. So your script must still be waiting for the expected window to appear. Which will lead you to double check your window title, probably you'll directly copy the window title with the *AutoIt Window Info Tool*, and this shows your mistake. Correct it. Viola, be happy =)

Besides: You don't need to run a Command-Prompt first, you can call `ShellExecute($file)` directly instead.

Comment: I typed an upper-case letter, turning it to a lower-case one solved the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the *AutoIt Window Info* tool, it helps with these issues, and it's also good practice to debug with `ConsoleWrite(...)`s.

For example, a simple one would be as before. However, you should probably use timeouts or variables and use the return for success/fail.

```
WinWaitActive("Window")
ConsoleWrite("Success")
Send("{DOWN}")
ConsoleWrite("Success")
```

Comment: You can even use `ConsoleWrite(WinWaitActive("Window") & @CR)` to see the return code and then wonder why this output was never written ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use following syntax for **down** key enter

```
Send("{DOWN 2}")
```

and similar for **Up** key enter

```
Send("{UP 2}")
```